# Webforms - ajaxToolkit:TabContainer disapears in Safari

Tags: webforms, safari, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a master page with ScriptManager and a web form page using a ajaxToolkit:TabContainer.  The tab container disapears randomly in the Safari browser after the user does async postbacks.  The following error message is displayed in the developer tools console: "**With owner must be set before initializing**".  I am not sure what is causing the problem or how to fix it specially because it works fine in all other browsers (IE, Chrome, and Firefox)

Here is the error:

```
    Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: owner must be set before initialize
    initializeScriptResource.axd:1:8910
    endUpdateScriptResource.axd:1:49050
    _setPropertiesScriptResource.axd:1:49847
    createScriptResource.axd:1:50117
    (anonymous function)ManagePatientInventory.aspx:1
    add_initScriptResource.axd:1:61541
    (anonymous function)ManagePatientInventory.aspx:1
    appendChild
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6068
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
    _loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
    loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132    
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
_loadScriptsInternalScriptResource.axd:1:6132
```

Comment: What version of Ajax Control Toolkit do you use?

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading the Ajax Control Toolkit to its latest version, the issue seems to be resolved. Thanks for the comment Mikhail Tymchuk!